# Groovy-Convert a line of code into multi lines

Tags: groovy

I am using the below code in groovy to break a string into multiple lines based on \n character. However it is nto working. Please suggest.

The value stored in the variable TestFiled_c is= 
Question1 \n Answer1 \n Question2 \n Answer 2

```
def a=TestField_C;
println (a);
a=a.toString();
println (a)
setAttribute('TestField_c', a);
```

The output is same as the input string in both cases of println

Comment: It looks like the value of the TestField_C variable is already multiple lines. And calling `toString()` on a string will return itslef. What are you really trying to do? What value are you expecting to be printed out?

Comment: My input is Question1 \n Answer1 \n Question2 \n Answer 2 .. annd the output should be Question1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
def x = a.split('\n')[0]
println(x)
```